# GM Userscript to change doman name with HTML5 replaceState()

Tags: html, greasemonkey, same-origin-policy, pushstate

I am writing a Greasemonkey userscript, for a site which has two domains. Let's say `http://friendlyurl.com` and `http://ugly.url.com`. `http://friendlyurl.com/*` redirects to `http://ugly.url.com/*`.
One of the features I wanted to include in the userscript was rewriting the ugly URL to the friendly one using HTML5 `replaceState()`.

The code I had was:

```
(function() {
    if (history.replaceState) {
        var url = document.location.href.replace('ugly.url.com/', 'friendlyurl.com/');
        history.replaceState({}, document.title, url);
    }
})();
```

Until I realized this disobeys the Same-Origin policy. My question is: is there a workaround to switch the site's domain, potentially using the GM_* API? Obviously as this is a userscript the security issue is on a much lower scale.
My current guess is that it is not possible, but I thought I'd put the question out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history#The_replaceState%28%29.C2.A0method) cannnot be used to change the domain, for security reasons. Not even through a GM API.

See more details on the rules in [the HTML Standard for replaceState()](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-history-replacestate).

Comment: PS. More details on the rules: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/history.html#dom-history-replacestate

Comment: I thought this was the case. Thanks for clarifying.